# Amazon S3 changing object permissions retroactively

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, bucket

I have a current S3 bucket with existing files.

The bucket was originally a public bucket, I changed its permissions to be private, but I already have objects that were uploaded and have `public read` CannedACL permissions.

How do I change the permissions on all of the uploaded objects to private CannedACL?

Answer (score 3):

aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/ s3://my-bucket/ --metadata x-amz-meta-updated=1 --recursive --acl private

Comment: This is the correct answer, copying object into itself without updating metadata wouldn't work so "--metadata x-amz-meta-updated=1" is needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to change the permissions in-bulk.

You will use the `aws s3 cp` command. While this is a *copy* command, it can also be used to copy files *in place*, which simply changes their permissions.

For example:

```
aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/ s3://my-bucket/ --recursive --acl bucket-owner-full-control
```

(`bucket-owner-full-control`: Both the object owner and the bucket owner get FULL_CONTROL over the object.)

See also: [Amazon S3 File Permissions, Access Denied when copied from another account](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43728025/174777)

Comment: Having issues with the metadata - how do i copy the metadata too?