# AWS s3 : change permissions from public to private in single folder on a bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

How can I change ACL form public to private on the single folder in AWS s3?.

Right now I am using this command

```
aws s3 ls --recursive s3://<bucket-name> | cut -d' ' -f5- | awk '{print $NF}' | while read line; do
    echo "$line"
    aws s3api put-object-acl --acl private --bucket <bucket> --key "$line"
done
```

But this will change permissions on all the folders in bucket

Answer (score 3):

There are three ways to grant public access to objects in Amazon S3:

- **Access Control Lists (ACLs)** on an individual object — good for providing one-off access to specific objects
- A **Bucket Policy** on the S3 bucket — good for providing access to a whole bucket or a portion of a bucket
- A **Policy on an IAM User or IAM Role** — good for providing access to specific users

Please note that **there are no permissions on folder**. In fact, folders do not actually exist in Amazon S3 buckets (even though it might look like they do, they don't!).

All data in Amazon S3 is private by default. So, to answer your question of "How do I change from public to private access", the answer is **you should reverse whatever you did to make it public**. So, if you granted access via an ACL, then you should remove the public access via the ACL. (By the way, it is not recommended to use ACLs to grant public access. Consider using a Bucket Policy or IAM Policy instead.)

If you wish to change ACLs on existing objects, you can copy the objects on top of themselves, but specify a different ACL. You might need to also specify another field such as metadata to allow the change to take affect.

For an example, see: [Amazon S3 changing object permissions retroactively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50271322/174777)

Comment: @Jhon so there is no way to change the ACL on objects in single folder??. One thing I found that I need to manually change the ACL for each objects from the web UI

Comment: Preferably, you should never use an ACL to make anything public. Instead, use a Bucket Policy to control access to a path (folder). Changing an ACL on a folder will have no impact, since folders do not actually exist.

Comment: Yes I've removed the `getObjet` from the bucket policy but the problem is some objects uploaded with default public read.