# s3 change permissions recursively

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions

I have an s3 bucket that contains hundreds of files within subfolders.  I know that a small number of those files have public read permissions but I don't know which files they are.

I'd like to remove those permissions from all files so I need to either apply a new set of permissions recursively to all files in the bucket or list all files with public read permissions.

Comment: One option: http://hackoftheday.securitytube.net/2013/04/finding-publicly-readable-files-in-your.html

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the files to *themselves* (that is, overwrite themselves) while changing permissions.

It might involve adding a small change (eg adding some metadata) to allow the copy to happen:

```
aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/ s3://my-bucket/ --recursive --acl bucket-owner-full-control --metadata "One=Two"
```

See: [Amazon S3 File Permissions, Access Denied when copied from another account](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43728025/174777)