# How to change filepath names in Amazon S3 bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

all.

I have around 900 objects in the following structure:

```
s3/bucketname/INGESTIONDATE=2022-02-20/file.csv
s3/bucketname/INGESTIONDATE=2022-02-21/file.csv
s3/bucketname/INGESTIONDATE=2022-02-22/file.csv
```

etc..

I need to change the file path to:

```
s3/bucketname/ingest_date=2022-02-20/file.json
s3/bucketname/ingest_date=2022-02-21/file.json
s3/bucketname/ingest_date=2022-02-22/file.json
```

This is around 900 objects so I do not plan on doing it by hand through the console.

Also, I am not too bothered about the JSON conversion, I can do that. It is mainly changing the filepaths and copying to a new bucket.
Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64251412/is-there-a-simple-way-to-rename-s3-folder-via-boto3

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like using aws cli -

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucketname/ | awk '{print $4}' | while read f; do newf=${f//INGESTIONDATE/ingest_date/} && aws s3 mv s3://bucketname/${f} s3://bucketname/${newf%???}json ; done
```

- `aws s3 ls s3://bucketname/` - lists the files in the bucket
- `newf=${f//INGESTIONDATE/ingest_date/}` replace `INGESTIONDATE` with `ingest_date` and store in `newf`
- We iterate through the file names as `f` and corresponding `newf`
- And move the suffix of file from `csv` to `json`(`${newf%???}` removes the last 3 chars of `f`) using `aws mv` command

**For testing, you can run `aws mv` with `--dry-run` command to see the mv commands which would be ran.**

As pointed out by @Konrad, this assumes that there are no whitespace/newline chars in the filepath(which would make the `awk` return truncated file path).

Comment: Careful — just like POSIX files, S3 objects can have pretty much arbitrary characters in their names, including whitespace and newlines. Your code snippet will fail to handle these correctly.