# How to perform Amazon S3 bucket copy in C# SDK

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk

I need to copy the [EDIT: entire] contents of a bucket into another bucket.
The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41511034/1662268) implies that it can be done on the CLI, [EDIT: as a single operation (rather than looping over every record in the bucket)]

Can it be done via any C# SDKs?
We're currently using the `AWSSDK.S3` Nuget package SDK, but I can't see any methods in that package's AmazonClient that would allow this sort of copy?

Answer (score 2):

The **AWS SDK for .NET** supports copying objects from one bucket to another. However, you cannot copy ALL objects in a single call. See REF docs here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html?page=TS3Client.html&tocid=Amazon_S3_AmazonS3Client

The business logic to copy an object from one bucket to another can be found in the **AWS Code Library**, which contains hundreds of tested examples in supported programming languages.

For this use case, see:

[image]

URL - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/s3_example_s3_CopyObject_section.html

The code lib should be the first place to reference when you want to learn how to use the AWS SDK.

Comment: Yes, I know that I can copy a single object. But I'm looking to copy the entire bucket; and I'd rather not do it object-by-object if possible. But the code library doesn't have any links to anything that describe that :(

Comment: Question edited to clarify goal.

Comment: You are correct - looking at the .NET REF docs -- there is not a method that copies all objects at once. You would need to do it the way shown in the example above. See V3 client here -- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/TS3Client.html

Answer (score 0):

S3 Batch Operations, AWS Datasync, or S3 Replication could be options as well. These tools require more initial setup, but the actual data transfer will happen in a single request. If there are a lot of objects to copy or this process is run frequently, it may be easier to automate using one of these options.

See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/considering-four-different-replication-options-for-data-in-amazon-s3/ for a comparison of a few options.